# tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath not firing after swipe gesture is called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

This is a localized issue.  I'm going to post a lot of code, and provide a lot of explanation.  Hopefully... someone can help me with this.

In my application I have a "Facebook-style" menu.  The iOS Facebook app, to be more specific.  You can access this menu in two different ways.  You may either touch the menu button, or swipe to open the menu.  When one opens and closes the menu using the button, the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method fires perfectly upon touching the cell.  When one opens and closes the menu using the swipe method... it does not.  You have to touch the table cell twice for the method to fire.  The code for these methods are exactly the same in several classes, however, this is the only one I have an issue with.  Take a look; see if I'm dropping the ball somewhere:

```
#import "BrowseViewController.h"



@implementation BrowseViewController

@synthesize browseView, table, countriesArray, btnSideHome, btnSideBrowse, btnSideFave, btnSideNew, btnSideCall, btnSideBeset, btnSideEmail, btnSideCancelled, menuOpen, navBarTitle, mainSearchBar, tap;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Medium" size:20.0];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1.0];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.text = @"Countries";
self.navBarTitle.titleView = label;
[label sizeToFit];

CheckNetworkStatus *networkCheck = [[CheckNetworkStatus alloc] init];
BOOL internetActive = [networkCheck checkNetwork];

if (internetActive) {

    tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    tap.delegate = self;
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeLeft = 
    [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
    [oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeRight = 
    [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
    [oneFingerSwipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeRight];

    menuOpen = NO;
    table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    NSArray *countries = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"United States", @"Canada", @"Mexico", nil];
    self.countriesArray = countries;
} else {
    //No interwebz, notify user and send them to the home page
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:@"Failed to connect to the server. Please verify that you have an active internet connection and try again. If the problem persists, please call us at **********" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
    PassportAmericaViewController *homeView = [[PassportAmericaViewController alloc]
                                               initWithNibName:@"PassportAmericaViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeView animated:YES];
}

[super viewDidLoad];
}


-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
  return [countriesArray count];
  NSLog(@"Number of objecits in countriesArray: %i", [countriesArray count]);
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Medium" size:20.0];
  }


  NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

  cell.textLabel.text = [countriesArray objectAtIndex:row];

  return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)table
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *countrySelected = [countriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Campground *_Campground = [[Campground alloc] init];
_Campground.country = countrySelected;

StateViewController *stateView = [[StateViewController alloc]
                                    initWithNibName:@"StateView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
stateView._Campground = _Campground;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:stateView animated:YES];

}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

-(void) dismissKeyboard {

[mainSearchBar resignFirstResponder];

}

-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender{

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"slideMenu"]){
    UIView *sq = (__bridge UIView *) context;
    [sq removeFromSuperview];

}
}

- (IBAction)menuTapped {
NSLog(@"Menu tapped");
CGRect frame = self.browseView.frame;
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector( animationDidStop:finished:context: )];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"slideMenu" context:(__bridge void *)(self.browseView)];

if(!menuOpen) {
    frame.origin.x = -212;
    menuOpen = YES;
    table.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
else
{
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    menuOpen = NO;
    table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

self.browseView.frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(IBAction) sideHome:(id)sender{

CGRect frame = self.browseView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
self.browseView.frame = frame;
menuOpen = NO;
PassportAmericaViewController *homeView = [[PassportAmericaViewController alloc]
                                           initWithNibName:@"PassportAmericaViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:homeView animated:YES];
table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
-(IBAction) sideBrowse:(id)sender{

CGRect frame = self.browseView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
self.browseView.frame = frame;
menuOpen = NO;
BrowseViewController *browseView2 = [[BrowseViewController alloc]
                                    initWithNibName:@"BrowseView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:browseView2 animated:YES];
table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
-(IBAction) sideBeset:(id)sender{

CGRect frame = self.browseView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
self.browseView.frame = frame;
menuOpen = NO;
BesetCampgroundMapViewController *besetMapView = [[BesetCampgroundMapViewController alloc]
                                                  initWithNibName:@"BesetCampgroundMapView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:besetMapView animated:YES];
table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
-(IBAction) sideFave:(id)sender{

CGRect frame = self.browseView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
self.browseView.frame = frame;
menuOpen = NO;
FavoritesViewController *faveView = [[FavoritesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavoritesView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:faveView animated:YES];
table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


}
-(IBAction) sideNew:(id)sender{

CGRect frame = self.browseView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
self.browseView.frame = frame;
menuOpen = NO;
NewCampgroundsViewController *theNewCampView = [[NewCampgroundsViewController alloc]
                                                initWithNibName:@"NewCampgroundsView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theNewCampView animated:YES];
table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
-(IBAction) sideCancelled:(id)sender{

CGRect frame = self.browseView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
self.browseView.frame = frame;
menuOpen = NO;
CancelledCampgroundsViewController *cancCampView = [[CancelledCampgroundsViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithNibName:@"CancelledCampgroundsView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cancCampView animated:YES];
table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
-(IBAction) sideCall:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"Calling Passport America...");
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:**********"]];
table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
-(IBAction) sideEmail:(id)sender{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"mailto:***************"]];
table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}

-(void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked: (UISearchBar *)searchBar {
SearchViewController *search = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
NSString *searchText = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:mainSearchBar.text];
search.searchText = searchText;
[self dismissKeyboard];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:search animated:YES];
table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
menuOpen = NO;
CGRect frame = self.browseView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
self.browseView.frame = frame;

}

-(void) swipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
if (!menuOpen) {
    CGRect frame = self.browseView.frame;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector( animationDidStop:finished:context: )];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"slideMenu" context:(__bridge void *)(self.browseView)];
    frame.origin.x = -212;
    menuOpen = YES;
    self.browseView.frame = frame;
    table.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

} else {
    //menu already open, do nothing
}
}

-(void) swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
if (!menuOpen) {
    //menu closed, do nothing
} else {
    CGRect frame = self.browseView.frame;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector( animationDidStop:finished:context: )];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"slideMenu" context:(__bridge void *)(self.browseView)];
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    menuOpen = NO;
    self.browseView.frame = frame;
    table.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.table deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.table indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
NSLog(@"Memory Warning!");
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
self.table = nil;
self.countriesArray = nil;
self.browseView = nil;

[super viewDidUnload];

}

@end
```

Comment: I have the same issue, except me the tap is never fired after a vertical swipe

Answer (score -1):

Determine which cell the swipe takes place in, compute the index path, and call didSelectRowAtIndexPath from your gestureRecognizer code.

Comment: The swipe takes place on the view.  Not the cell.  The swipes do two things.  Open and close the menu.  That's it.

Comment: From your description, it seems that your problem is that the swipes don't call didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  If that is correct, then you can call it yourself from the swipe action code by determining which cell is under the swipe.

Comment: Here's the thing... I don't want the swipe to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  The swipe has nothing to do with any action taking place on the tableView.  The swipe just opens and closes the side menu.  The problem is... once the user swipes to close the menu, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method doesn't fire the first time you touch the cell on the tableView.  You have to touch it twice.  I have table.userInteractionEnabled = YES; in the swipe method to close the menu.